# Best backup apps for Windows?

Tags: windows, backup

Which apps are the best when it comes to backing up and restoring a machine running Microsoft Windows. Preferably they should have functionary like snapshot in Vmware or something else for backing up and restoring really quickly.

Answer (score 2):

There is [Acronis](http://www.acronis.com)

Pros:

- Compatible with Windows.
- Good compression.
- Schedulable.
- Working priority.
- Disk or folder based backup.
- Fast incrementals.
- Burnable recovery software.
- Compatible with VM's.

The disk based option makes a clone of the drive.
Cons:

- Not free.
- Initial backups may take long.

I don't know any prices because of the different licences available.
There is also an option to store backups in the cloud which I haven't used.